# How to clip or mask entity in android/andengine?

Tags: android, opengl-es, andengine, masking, clipping

I want to implement masking with sprite in Andengine. I want same functionality as in ios class called

> SKCropNode

which works like an masking node! Is there any workaround like this in andengine/opengl ? Thanks.

Edit: This is something I was trying to mask an entity, got no effect, any suggestion?

```
public class ClippingEntity extends Entity//BaseSprite
{

protected int mWidth;
protected int mHeight;

public ClippingEntity(float pX, float pY, int pWidth, int pHeight, TextureRegion t)
{
    super(pX, pY);//, pWidth, pHeight, t);
    mWidth = pWidth;
    mHeight = pHeight;
}

@Override
protected void onManagedDraw(GL10 pGL, Camera pCamera)
{

    pGL.glPushMatrix();
    {

        pGL.glEnable(GL10.GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
        pGL.glScissor(0 + (int) mX, 800 - mHeight + (int) mY, mWidth, mHeight);

        super.onManagedDraw(pGL, pCamera);

        pGL.glDisable(GL10.GL_SCISSOR_TEST);

    }
    pGL.glPopMatrix();

}
```

I have also tried Stencil Test but it just clears the color of rectangle.
ref: [opengl mask tests](https://open.gl/depthstencils)

Ultimate goal is to disable drawing changes in specific entity where it may aslo have transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work:

```
 @Override
 protected void onManagedDraw(final GLState pGLState, final Camera pCamera)
 {
    pGLState.pushProjectionGLMatrix();
    pGLState.enableScissorTest();
    GLES20.glScissor(0 + (int) mX, 800 - mHeight + (int) mY, mWidth, mHeight);
    super.onManagedDraw(pGLState, pCamera);
    pGLState.disableScissorTest();
    pGLState.popProjectionGLMatrix();
}
```

For GLES1, try this:
http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles1/clipping-effect-t2962.html

Comment: As you can see in my question in managedDraw function it uses GL10. Your function is based on GL20. So that I Can't find above functions of opengl. And I already have tried simple scissor test but got nothing!

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I thought you're using GLES2. I will update the original answer.